# Removing certain LaTeX preview matchers from Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

Is there a way to make certain matchers be ignored when I run `org-latex-preview`? For example, I don't want the TeX dollar signs to be rendered, nor `\begin` environments. My reason for this is because I am using the [org-fragtog](https://github.com/io12/org-fragtog) package, and I run into issues with nested matched environments.

I did remove all the matchers I don't want from `org-format-latex-options`, but that does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be an issue in the org source. The relevant function, `org-format-latex`, contains a line

```
(let* ((math-regexp "\\$\\|\\\\[([]\\|^[ \t]*\\\\begin{[A-Za-z0-9*]+}")
```

which indicates that the latex regex is hard-coded in this case. In other words `:matchers` does not work right now. It ought to be fixed with the next major update to org's latex handling: https://list.orgmode.org/orgmode/87lek2up0w.fsf@tec.tecosaur.net/.